# Can't replicate HTML code with Ruby on Rails 4 code

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to replicate this HTML code

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" id="2" name="check" />
<label style="left: 0px;"for="2"><span>Name</span>
```

using this Ruby On Rails 4 code

```
<%= check_box_tag 'reason_ids[]', reason.id, false ,:required => true%>
<label style="left: 0px;"for="2"><span>Name</span>
```

So far I am getting the same visual appearance like HTML produces, but not the same functionality.

**My goal:**
Click on label also checks checkbox.

At this point I can't check checkbox with  click neither on checkbox or label. I have tried to change order of Rails code, but without success.

What I am doing wrong ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal:

> Click on label also checks checkbox

You need to "connect" an input-label pair by id-for (input-id and label-for should have the same value):

```
<%= check_box_tag 'reason_ids[]', reason.id, false, :required => true, :id => reason.id %>
<label style="left: 0px;" for="2"><span>Name</span>
```

**Note:** added `:id => reason.id` to check_box_tag

---

Alternatively (different technique), you can wrap the check_box under a label (without the need to associate id-for):

```
<%= label_tag do %>
  <span>Name</span>
  <%= check_box_tag 'reason_ids[]', reason.id, false, :required => true %>
<% end %>
```